# Numpy : multivariate indexing?

Tags: numpy, indexing

I wander, is it possible to index several dimensions at once ? With some broadcasting. Example :

Suppose i have an array `A`, shaped `(n,d)`. Suppose i have a indexing array, say `I` with integer values between `0` and `d-1`. Set `B = A[:,I]`.

If `shape(I) == (k,)`, for whaterver `k`, then `B` has shape `(n,k)` and `B[x,y] = A[x,I[y]]`.

But if `shape(I) == (k,p)` for whatever `(k,p)`, then i wanted `B` to be shaped `(n,k,p)` with `B[x,y,z] = A[x,I[y,z]]`.

1° How can i get this behavior ?

2° Does it have a drawback i did not see ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it exactly as you described it:

```
import numpy as np
n = 100
d = 20
k = 10
p = 17

A = np.random.random((n, d))
I = np.random.randint(low=0, high=d, size=(k, p))
B = A[:, I]
print(B.shape)  # (n, k, p)

# Testing if the new array B is constructed as expected
x = 3
y = 5
z = 7
print(B[x, y, z])
print(A[x, I[y, z]])
print(B[x, y, z] == A[x, I[y, z]])
```

Its hard to answer if this is a good implementation or not, without context. But in general it is a good idea to use numpy and vectorization if you have speed in mind.

Comment: I dont know what got me confused. I think i have trouble undertanding what is the difference between masking and indexing, i'll read on that. Thanks for the reminder anyway ! You made my day..